# How to replace UIPickerView with native keyboard back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview

I need to dynamically change the input for UITextField: keyboard with pickerView and back (pickerView with keyboard).

I know how to substitute keyboard with pickerView - via `input` property of textfield.

But I don't know to substitute pickerView with keyboard back. How can I do this?

The flow is following:

- user need to enter some value into textfield (typing via keyboard)
- then I'll show them some clarification options via pickerView, user select any option and it will appear into textfield
- then user should be able to edit the selected value in the textfield via native keyboard

Thank you

Comment: Did you try setting the text field's `inputView` to `nil`?

Comment: not yet, but I thought about it - will try now

Comment: > If the value in this property is nil, the text field displays the standard system keyboard when it becomes first responder. Assigning a custom view to this property causes that view to be presented instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
textfield.inputView = nil;
```

and if you want to show keyboard directly after then you can use

```
[textfield becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope this will work. :)